# Outlook 2007 : Recover deleted emails that I have sent

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, email-client, exchange-2007

I want to know if there is a way to recover emails deleted from the trash. I have deleted them from the trash accidentally. But there were initially deleted from sent folder.
Please do not get confused here, I can already recover emails, but, I noticed that sent emails precisely are not present when using this [link](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Recover-deleted-items-6b02f698-13e4-49da-8eed-ada57aca8445).

Comment: Not sure about outlook 2007 but in 2013 you can right click the folder and select "recover deleted items".

Comment: I imagine you got a downvote because google has as the second response to "outlook 2007 recover deleted items": https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Recover-deleted-items-6b02f698-13e4-49da-8eed-ada57aca8445

Comment: What kind of mail account/connection is it?

Comment: Exchange account

Answer (score 1):

This is straight from [the link I posted in the comments](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Recover-deleted-items-6b02f698-13e4-49da-8eed-ada57aca8445). It assumes the use of Exchange.

Recover deleted items
This feature requires you to use a Microsoft Exchange Server 2000, Exchange Server 2003, or Exchange Server 2007 account. Most home and personal accounts do not use Microsoft Exchange.

Microsoft Office Outlook 2007 provides a way to recover items after you delete them permanently, even after you empty the Deleted Items folder.

NOTE   Your Exchange administrator specifies the retention time for items that are deleted permanently on the server running Exchange. After this time elapses, you cannot recover the deleted items.

You can view and recover deleted items, including the items that were deleted permanently, when you selected items and pressed SHIFT+DELETE or SHIFT+  Button image.

In the folder from where you deleted the item, or in the Deleted Items folder, click Recover Deleted Items on the Tools menu.

Recover items that you have previously deleted

The Recover Deleted Items command is missing

You must use an Exchange account for this command to appear. If you use an Exchange account and do not see the command, contact your Exchange administrator.

Click an item and then click Recover Selected Items Button image.

TIP   To select multiple items, press CTRL as you click each item.

Each recovered item is restored to the folder from which it was deleted.

NOTE   You cannot recover an item if it does not appear in the Recover Deleted Items dialog box.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but it is not working in my case. I did an experience by going to my sent folder, delete an email, then go to the trash, and try to recover it, but the mail was not there! I could see many emails, but it was only emails received!!!